# CKEditor automatically adding <pre> tag in my content

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have been trying to add Hindi Language Content in my db, so when i make an api request the data gets added in the Hindi language as i need but `<pre>` tag gets added to it.

Using CkEditor like this

```
<CKEditor
     data={this.state.Description}
     style={{width:'60%'}}
     onChange={this.onEditorChange} 
     className="textFontSize"/> 



onEditorChange( e ) {
  console.log(e)
  this.setState( {
  Description: e.editor.getData()
  });
}
```

and then while sending `this.state.Description` with  my api  in have something like this in my db

```
 <pre>लोरम इप्सम केवल मुद्रण और टंकण उद्योग का डमी ।</pre>
```

Comment: And you want to remove the `<pre>` tags before storing? What's your backend language?

Comment: @GetSet yupp and Nodejs with mysql as db!

Comment: It doesn't seem like a hard problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @GetSet just tried  <CKEditor
           disallowedContent ="pre"
            data={this.state.Description}
    
                onChange={this.onEditorChange} 
               /> on react side

Comment: as i only found this solution somewhere and am pretty new with CKEdtior

Comment: What about on your server side?

Comment: @GetSet dude no clue how can i manage pre tag in server side thisis mine first project and hint ?

Answer (score 0):

You can sanitize the input in `onChange` listener.

```
onEditorChange( e ) {
  var data = e.editor.getData();
  data = data.startsWith("<pre>") ? data.substr(5) : data;
  data = data.endsWith("</pre>") ? data.substr(0, data.length-6) : data;

  this.setState({
    Description: e.editor.getData()
  });
}
```